# remove underlining in Lubuntu

Tags: command-line, keyboard, lubuntu, input-language, input-method

I have updated my Lubuntu 16.04 LTS to Artful Aardvark. After updates I have this strange underlining happening when I type. It doesn't matter whether I type to the terminal or for example to the browser (input fields or even typing here this text. Taking a screenshot erases the typed word).

The underline appears under a new word or a part of the word as I type and after a second or a whitespace the underline is removed. The newly typed word remains. The weirdest is when I use `sudo`. When I am asked to type the password, the password I type gets underlined and with it the password appears. When I click somewhere else outside of the terminal window or press whitespace character, my password dissapears.

And it is not systematic. Sometimes I type a whole paragraph and no underlining when suddenly it happens again.

And I'm using quite an old laptop, if this should be somehow important.

Any help?

Comment: `sudo` does not echo the password as you type it. As such, it must be the terminal emulator doing this. I suspect it's related to your IM (input method) settings.

Comment: It  seems that there might have gone something wrong when I upgraded my Lubuntu. `os-release` shows that I am running 18.04 LTS (bionic beaver), `lsb-release -a` shows I am running an 16.04 LTS (Xenial). The repositories that my laptop downloaded data were (I believe) Artful Aardvark. Perhaps my issue comes from that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same symptoms with the weird underlined input buffer. It turned to be uim (a multilingual input method library and environment) that was toggled when I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

You can disable the key binding by open `uim-pref-gtk`, go to `Global key bindings 1`>`[Global] on` and remove `"<Shift>space"` and apply.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286049/when-im-typing-a-text-in-english-it-gets-underlined-and-behaves-bizarrely

Comment: The same thing happened to me when upgrading Xubuntu LTS 16.04 to 18.04. This undocumented change was driving me crazy. Thanks!

Comment: Wow - that solved the issue I had. I vaguely remembered which keys might be responsible; at first I thought it was KDE Konsole, since I typed there before, but then I realized it can not be KDE konsole since this input-problem also happened when I was typing in the browser. Your advice solved my problem 100% - that was weird, never heard of uim before. Makes me question the usability of that because I was accidentally (!) hitting that key combination. I am a sloppy typer.